# How do I disconnect from wireless after exiting the browser?

Tags: wifi, web-browsers

When I launch the browser, it activates a wireless connection, but it doesn't disconnect when I quit the browser.

How do I turn wifi off after a session?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Add a tag with the operating system you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding something. Things doesn't work like that. Whenever pi is booted ,by default it automatically connects you with  the wifi. And it stays open unless you close the connection. You can close the connection with a left click on the network menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut which opens your browser and deactivates wifi: `browser && iwconfig wlan0 down`
Replace `browser` with your browser. 
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/489525/activate-deactivate-wi-fi-on-lenovo-b5400-under-ubuntu-14-04